# Оформление библиографического описания

Tags: общие-вопросы

Название книги на араб. языке. Каир, 1991. (немецкий перевод: Название на немецком. Штутгарт, 1995).
Правильно ли стоят точки перед и после скобок?
Или правильнее без скобок:
...1991. Немецкий...1995.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А откуда дровишки? Под названием кавычки?

Нетути в библиографических описаниях никаких кавычек.

А напротив, есть ГОСТ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Правила оформления списка литературы и библиографических ссылок](http://www.polytech21.ru/rekomendatsii-po-oformleniyu)

---

[Требования к оформлению. Библиографическое описание](http://tshi.tomsk.ru/index.php/home-8/2012-01-22-14-33-20)

---

[ГОСТ 7.1-2003 БИБЛИОГРАФИЧЕСКАЯ ЗАПИСЬ](http://dis.finansy.ru/ofr/gost7-1-2003.htm)

Пример:

> Олпорт Г. Становление личности. М.: Смысл, 2002. Пер. изд.: Allport
>   G.W. Personality: a psychological interpretation. New York: Holt,
>   1937.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не кавычки, а скобки (заработался...). В вопросе исправил. А разве не надо/можно указать язык перевода?

Comment: Радик, ты по первой ссылочке походи - там много примеров. Я не очень понимаю, зачем двум книгам стоять рядом в библиографии. Но если уж, то: вместо скобок ставится когда косая (слеш), когда сдвоенная она же.

Comment: Дается книга на арабском, которую найти и тем более прочитать сложнее, а ее перевод на немецкий или другой буржуйский язык - легче.  Как я понял, слэши ставятся в описании ОДНОЙ книги, а здесь - две разных (хотя одна и является переводом другой). Может быть все-таки вариант:   
Название книги на араб. языке. Каир, 1991. Немецкий перевод: Название на немецком. Штутгарт, 1995.      
будет правильным?

Comment: Радик, и чего мучиться? Создай прецедент. Я всегда так поступаю. Перед кем нам отчёт держать? Мы делаем а) как понятнее, б) как хотим. Точность в библиографии важна только для библиотечной картотеки, - это твой случай?

Comment: Так и сделаем. Спасибо!